# Build SQL list that returns a table based on whats not on other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that builds me a list of users. I want that list of users to exclude users that appear on another query generated list.  for instance this first query:

```
    SELECT [UUID] 
  ,[UserName]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[EmployeeNumber]
      ,[Inactive] 
  ,[EmployeeType] 
 FROM [PCA].[dbo].[Users] b Where Plant ='610' AND FirstName != 'Ei'AND FirstName != 'Recovery' AND LastName != 'Production' AND LastName != 'Lab' AND LastName != 'Kiln' AND FirstName != 'Pulp'AND FirstName != 'Roll'AND FirstName != 'Valdosta' AND FirstName != 'Guard'AND FirstName != 'Paper'AND FirstName != 'Power'AND FirstName != 'Powerhouse' AND FirstName != 'E&I' AND LastName != 'Operator' AND LastName != 'Maintenance' AND FirstName != 'Maintenance' AND LastName != 'Tender' AND FirstName != 'Accounting' AND Inactive = 0 And EmployeeType != 'S' AND EmployeeType != 'C'AND EmployeeType != '' AND FirstName <> LastName AND b.UserName in(Select a.USLanID from [HDData].[dbo].[tblUsers] a)
```

build a list of 145 hourly paid users.  now this second list has seven users that have been hurt within the specified time frame describe in the query. i want the first list to have all that users on it that do not appear on the second query list. so those people that got hurt on the second query should not appear on the first list. i should have 138 users on my first list after it is all said and done.  how can i do this i tried using a "not in" clause but they still appear.  below is my second list which also has a UUID colum name Employee:

```
SELECT * FROM [IncidentReporting].[dbo].[IncidentReports] WHERE Classification IN ('RE','FA') AND IncidentDate between DATEADD(Year, -1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00') AND '2017-02-09 00:00:00' AND ForceClosed = 0 AND IncidentType != 'C' AND ApprovalStatus = 'A'
```

This is what i have tried but returns same amount of rows with the injured users on it as well.

```
    DECLARE @Date As DateTime
DECLARE @PrevCalenderYear As DateTime


SET @PrevCalenderYear = datetimefromparts(year(@Date), 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00)
SET @Date = GetDate()




SELECT [UUID] 
  ,[UserName]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[EmployeeNumber]
      ,[Inactive] 
  ,[EmployeeType] 
   FROM [PCA].[dbo].[Users] b Where Plant ='610' AND FirstName != 'Ei'AND FirstName != 'Recovery' AND LastName != 'Production' AND LastName != 'Lab' AND LastName != 'Kiln' AND FirstName != 'Pulp'AND FirstName != 'Roll'AND FirstName != 'Valdosta' AND FirstName != 'Guard'AND FirstName != 'Paper'AND FirstName != 'Power'AND FirstName != 'Powerhouse' AND FirstName != 'E&I' AND LastName != 'Operator' AND LastName != 'Maintenance' AND FirstName != 'Maintenance' AND LastName != 'Tender' AND FirstName != 'Accounting' AND Inactive = 0 And EmployeeType != 'S' AND EmployeeType != 'C'AND EmployeeType != '' AND FirstName <> LastName AND b.UserName in(Select a.USLanID from [HDData].[dbo].[tblUsers] a) AND b.UUID NOT IN (SELECT c.Employee FROM [IncidentReporting].[dbo].[IncidentReports] c WHERE Classification IN ('RE','FA') AND IncidentDate between DATEADD(Year, -1, @PrevCalenderYear) AND @Date AND ForceClosed = 0 AND IncidentType != 'C' AND ApprovalStatus = 'A')
```

Comment: Please do not tag databases which are not relevant to your question.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax shown in the question

Comment: @ John Conde, User table and the Incident reporting table are relevant to the query im trying to build....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Date As DateTime
DECLARE @PrevCalenderYear As DateTime

SET @PrevCalenderYear = datetimefromparts(year(@Date), 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00)
SET @Date = GetDate()

select @PrevCalenderYear
```

returns `null` because `@Date` is `null` when you call it for setting `@PrevCalenderYear`.

corrected:

```
DECLARE @Date As DateTime;
DECLARE @PrevCalenderYear As DateTime;

SET @Date = GetDate();
SET @PrevCalenderYear = datetimefromparts(year(@Date), 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, 00);

select @PrevCalenderYear;
```

returns: `2017-01-01 00:00:00`

---

In your last query, you remove a year from `@PrevCalender`, so I'm not sure why we don't just do that in the beginning. We can also clean up some of the `!=` lists using `not in()`, and instead of using `in (select ...)` and `not in select (...)` we can use `exists()` and `not exists()`. (We can also change 'Calender' to 'Calendar'.)

```
declare @Date datetime, @PrevCalendarYear datetime;

set @Date = GetDate();
/*2016-01-01*/
set @PrevCalendarYear = dateadd(year , datediff(year , 0, getdate())-1, 0) 

select 
   [uuid]
 , [UserName]
 , [FirstName]
 , [LastName]
 , [EmployeeNumber]
 , [Inactive]
 , [EmployeeType]
from [pca].[dbo].[Users] b
where 1=1
  and Plant = '610'
  and Inactive = 0
  and FirstName <> LastName
  and EmployeeType not in ('','C','S')
  and FirstName not in (
    'Accounting' ,'E&I' ,'Ei' ,'Guard' ,'Maintenance' ,'Paper' 
    ,'Power' ,'Powerhouse' ,'Pulp' ,'Recovery' ,'Roll' ,'Valdosta'
    ) 
  and LastName not in (
    'Kiln' ,'Lab' ,'Maintenance' ,'Operator' ,'Production' ,'Tender'
    )
  and exists (
  select 1
    from [hddata].[dbo].[tblUsers] a
    where a.uslanid=b.[UserName]
  )
  and not exists (
  select 1
    from [IncidentReporting].[dbo].[IncidentReports] c
    where c.Employee = b.[uuid]
      and c.Classification in ('re', 'fa')
      --and IncidentDate between 
        --dateadd(Year, - 1, @PrevCalendarYear) /*2016-01-01*/ and @Date 
      --and IncidentDate >= dateadd(year , datediff(year , 0, getdate())-1, 0)
      --and IncidentDate <= getdate()
      and c.IncidentDate >= @PrevCalendarYear
      and c.IncidentDate <= @Date
      and c.ForceClosed = 0
      and c.IncidentType != 'C'
      and c.ApprovalStatus = 'A'
  )
```